# What is the proper option when filling dropdownlist in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am filling a list and pass it to another component. The list is used as options of a dropdownlist and I am not sure what is the proper way to fill this list. Here is the service method and the related methods:

**service.ts**

```
list(): Observable<CarDto> { }
```

**parent.html**

```
<child-component [cars]="cars" *ngIf="cars && cars.length > 0"> </child-component>
```

or should I use `async` ?

```
<child-component [cars]="cars$ | async" *ngIf="((cars$ | async) && (cars$ | async)?.length > 0"> </child-component
```

**parent.ts**

```
cars: any;

listCars() {
  this.service.list().subscribe((list: CarDto) => {
    this.cars= list.cars;
});
```

or should I use `async` ?, Promise, etc???

```
 cars$: Observable<any>;

 this.cars$ = this.service.list().pipe(shareReplay());
```

**child.ts**

```
@Input() cars: any;
```

What is the proper way for this scenario? As the data is not changed during lifecycle, the only thing to keep attention to load parent and child components fastly without any problem. On the other hand, pleasekeep in mind that my service method returns `Observable`.

Comment: I would use `async` because `async` will unsubscribe from the subscription once component is destroyed. Doing `.subscribe` will not unsubscribe from the observable.
https://brianflove.com/2016-12-11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/

Comment: Yes, I also would like to use it but unfortunately when using it as shown above, I could not load child components properly. So, may it be related to my service that returns Observable?

Comment: I am not sure, maybe it is related to the `*ngIf`? It seems like the brackets are off. An extra `(`.

Comment: I checked and if there is an eror linter warned be. Most probably using observalve causes thie latency. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async pipe is the way you should prefer from a best practice point of view. But using the async pipe on the same observable is not good. Please consider wrapping your template in a `ng-container` which stores the value for you.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="cars$ | async as cars">
  <child-component [cars]="cars" *ngIf="cars && cars.length > 0"></child-component>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Very interesting and fatal tip I think. But what is the difference when using or not using ng-container? I cannot understand the difference completely. Any detail pls?

Comment: With this approach only 1 subscription is added

Comment: Voted up. Actually the problem I encountered with this approach is that I cannot loaded the chil component to the page properly. But maybe `ng-container` would fix the problem.